# Cannot run rails from command line with rvm installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, path, rvm

I have just made a fresh install of rvm with rails on a fresh Linux Mint machine
I can see that rails is installed in my gems

```
gem query --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

...other stuff ...
rails (3.2.8)
...other stuff ...
```

but if I try to run from console I cannot see it

```
$ rails -v
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

this is my PATH variable

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/motta/.rvm/bin
```

what should I add to the path to have rails available?
thank you

UPDATE: 
This is the output of rvm list

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

The installation has been done following the rvm instructions
https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

**SOLVED:**
When I finished the installation I found out that rvm modified my /home/user/.bashrc file
with this line

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

therefore I thought that the following one was not needed anymore, which is not the case

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

adding the one above to .bashrc solved my problem

Comment: Can you see rails gem when you run gem list command.
Also are you able to see list of rvm using rvm list command.

Comment: What does `which gem` output?

Comment: anybody answer that helpful to you then accept that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow this steps for installing RVM and then install rails

http://rails.vandenabeele.com/blog/2011/11/26/installing-ruby-and-rails-with-rvm-on-ubuntu-11-dot-10/

or

https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH is obviously set wrong, make sure you use ruby:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

To make this persistent for next sessions set the default:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default        #OR:
rvm alias create default 1.9.3
```

Finally you might need to enable login shell to make it working (there are few answers on this topic already).